# Iphone Application status in iTunes Connect

Tags: iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

Its been 7 long days since i uploaded my app and the status of my app is still in "waiting for review".

Now I have started wondering if i have done something wrong? As far as i know i did all the formalities well and uploaded the app in Application loader. Since this is my first application, I am very nervous.

I read somewhere it takes around a week or a little more than that. Should i not count the weekends and the national holidays?

Some help or words of wisdom would be great.!

Comment: Just be patient. 7 days is just normal time. When nothing happened after 14 days I would wonder. And when nothing happened after three weeks I would send Apple an email. After it changed to 'in review' normally it takes 1-5 days until you get a mail (good or bad).

Comment: That's the way it is. Be patient.

Comment: Patience is a virtue - you simply need to wait until you hear back. Review times fluctuate and can be a bit longer than two weeks.

Comment: You'll find some stats in here http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/4320-appstore-wait-thread.html ... average with my experience is 2 weeks for a new submission or up to 1 week for an app update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First time it will take 10-15 days to review. after this updated version will take 7-10 days. so not be nervous.

Thx

Answer (score 1):

If you did something wrong then it would have been rejected. Waiting for review means it is still pending. It may take more than one week, and it generally takes more than one week. So just be patient.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it took almost 14 days.
i guess it depends also on the size of your app and how many screens and functions do you have , cause as i know they go threw every single screen and function on every kind of device that you support :)